# ADT and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, containers, virtual, adt

So I have this code:

```
bool array::InputArray(const ObjectPtr& obj) {
    if(full()) return false;
    if(!duplicate(vet)) throw exception("\nImportant exception");
    obj->input(cin);
    arr[nelem]=obj;
    nelem++;
    return true;
}
```

`obj->input(cin)` is just a polymorph function to permit input from console for the exact derived class, the main program gives the right object so that virtual function is not a problem but the `arr[nelem]=obj;` is, also "arr" is as defined:

```
object* arr;
```

My goal is: I want this array to contain the right object when given in the main program, but it only contains the base class side.. how do I tell the compiler to insert even the derived side?? Thanks!

Comment: How was `input()` declared in the base class? Post a [mcve] that reproduces your problem as required here please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is note quite consistent between the type of `obj` and the type of `arr`.  Nevertheless, according to the symptoms,  your problem is due to [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing):

```
arr[nelem]=obj;
```

Because, according to your definition of `arr`, `arr[nelem]` would be of type `object` here, which is the base class.  So whatever the real derived type of `obj`,  it will be converted back to the base class (and hence use the virtual functions of the base class).

If you want to have a polymorphic container, you need to have a container of pointers,  or better, smart pointers.  And instead of arrays, you should really consider using vectors:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> arr;

bool array::InputArray(std::shared_ptr<Object> obj) {
    ...
    obj->input(cin);
    arr.push_back(obj);  // no need for nelem.  Use arr.size() instead
    return true;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/moDdjL)